# How to validate different method of clustering

Tags: clustering, similarity

I have applied K-means and Hierarchical Agglomerative clustering method on some data and clustered them into 5 groups. For validation (agreement) purpose I used this formula:

```
c=(# of cluster shared/ Total cluster)*100 %
```

I feel its a wrong validation technique.

Can I use entropy, Rand index, Dunn number etc to measure the validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could always try a **[silhouette score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering))**, although it may not perform well on high dimensional data.

Silhouette scores compare a datapoint's placement relative to its own cluster to its placement relative to other cluster/clusters.  The values returned will range between -1 (indicating a poor clustering) to +1 (indicating "good" clustering).  Using Wikipedia's example, use 2 clusters and assume there is an observation ***i*** that has been placed in Cluster 1.  The Silhouette score uses distance measures (Euclidean, for example, but others can also be used) to determine the average distance of ***i***' to every other point in Cluster 1.  Then it determines the average distance of ***i*** to every point in Cluster 2.  The silhouette formula for point ***i*** would be:

***silhouette***(i) = $\frac{b(i)-a(i)}{Max\left \{ a(i), b(i) \right \}}$

Remembering for this example that ***i*** is in Cluster 1, then:

- If an object is closer, on average, to the points in Cluster 1 than
  Cluster 2, then a(i) < b(i) and silhouette score is positive for that
  point.
- If an object is closer, on average, to the points in Cluster 2 than
  Cluster 1, then a(i) > b(i) and silhouette score is negative for that
  point.

Run this comparison across all points and all clusters, then average, and you will obtain a global silhouette score.

You will see most people capture silhouette score in a for loop where they vary the number of clusters; this allows quick comparison of a range of clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Define "shared". Don't assume cluster 1 in A is cluster 1 in B. The numbers are meaningless.

So yes, you should use standard techniques like adjusted Rand index.